# Why are my Delta E values accross all image higher than 100?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, colors, computer-vision

I am using the simplest version of Delta E (Delta E 76). My goal is to calculate Delta E accross 2 images (not only between 2 color codes). The return of that image should be a cv::Mat with 1 channel and height x width the same as original image. The pixel values for the resulted image are Delta E results for both of those images.
As it is denoted, the images are completly opposite if Delta E is 100 (which means that it cannot be > 100). After I run the following code, and when I output the DeltaE image I can see that some of the values are over 100. Can anybody help me find a mistake which I have done?

```
cv::Mat ImageProcessor::CalculateDeltaETest(cv::Mat& gTImage, cv::Mat& srcImage)
{
    cv::Mat gTImageCopy;
    gTImage.copyTo(gTImageCopy);

    int height = gTImage.rows;
    int width = gTImage.cols;
    cv::resize(srcImage, srcImage, cv::Size(width, height), cv::INTER_LINEAR);
        // Converting images to Lab colorspace
    cv::cvtColor(gTImageCopy, gTImageCopy, cv::COLOR_BGR2Lab);
    cv::cvtColor(srcImage, srcImage, cv::COLOR_BGR2Lab);
        
    cv::Mat diff, diff16B, sqRoott;
        // Calculating difference accross pixels
    cv::absdiff(srcImage, gTImageCopy, diff);
        // Conversion needed because if I square the diff image, then values might get over 255
    diff.convertTo(diff16B, CV_16U);
    cv::Mat squaredDiff = diff16B.mul(diff16B);
    squaredDiff.convertTo(squaredDiff, CV_16U);
    cv::Mat summed(squaredDiff.rows, squaredDiff.cols, CV_16U);
        // Summing over LAB channels into a single channel
    cv::transform(squaredDiff, summed, cv::Matx13f(1, 1, 1));
        // Converting to float because cv::sqrt works with floats
    summed.convertTo(summed, CV_32F);
    sqRoott.convertTo(sqRoott, CV_32F);
    cv::sqrt(summed, sqRoott);
        // Changing the resulting image into a normal CV_8U pixel code format
    sqRoott.convertTo(sqRoott, CV_8U);
    return sqRoott;
}
```

At first I only used 8 bit char pixel formats but realised that squerred values might go over 255. After changeing pixel values I still noticed in the plotted **sqRoott** image that some values are over 100.

Comment: Since you're converting it to CV_32F eventually anyway, why not do it right away and skip the CV_16U?  Might save you some overflow issues.